# How to integrate Redis in an existing NodeJS & Express, Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, redis, sequelize.js

How can I integrate **Redis**, and which problems can **Redis** solve in an existing NodeJS, Express & Postgres Application. Thank you in advance Mates :).

I wanted to Know, how I can Implement this technology to improve my Application Performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use [Redis](https://redis.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/overview/) cloud. It was very easy to implement. Another option I have been practicing is using Docker.[About Redis](https://redis.io/docs/about/)

```
const redis =require("redis");
require("dotenv").config();


let client =  redis.createClient({
    url:`redis://default:${process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD}@${process.env.REDIS_HOST}:${parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT)}`
})
              .on('connect', () => logger.info('Redis Client Connected'))
              .on('error', () => logger.error('Redis Client Error'))



module.exports = client;
```